# Qt5, lambda and scope of vars

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, qt5

I have a QLocalServer in Qt5, which is connected to the `newConnection()` signal.

That signal calls this function:

```
QLocalSocket *clientConnection = m_server->nextPendingConnection();
clientID++; // <--- declared in header
clientConnection->setProperty("ID", QVariant(clientID));

connect(clientConnection, &QLocalSocket::disconnected, [clientConnection](){
    qDebug() << "Client disconnected " << clientConnection->property("ID");
    clientConnection->deleteLater();
});
```

If two clients (client ID 1 and client ID 2) connect one after other, and then client 1 disconnects, what will happen inside the lambda function? I mean, after the second client has connected, what will happen with the value of `clientConnection`? Will it get overriden (so the `clientConnection` of the first client won't be valid anymore) or will each have valid data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each instance of a lambda closure type has its own storage for members captured by value.

```
int i = 1;
auto l1 = [i]() { return i; };    // captures 1
i = 2;
auto l2 = [i]() { return i; };    // captures 2
l1();    // returns 1
l2();    // returns 2
```